# how to place a link in smarty using javascript?

Tags: javascript, smarty

I am new in Smarty.So Please tell me how to direct on another page from button's onclick event.
I have following code in my(xxxx.tpl) file.

```
  <input type="button" style="height:20px;"class="button" value="Back"></td> 

  {literal}
  <script type="java script>
  </script>
  </literal>
```

I dont know how to redirect page. i kindly help me.
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want to do. Redirects are done from the server using an HTTP status header 301 or 302. What you want to do sound like a simple link to another page. In that case, just use an anchor element and style it as a button. I also can't see how a template language relates to redirects?!

Comment: feeela . i want to redirect on my another page like abc.php

Comment: wrap the button with a link. TADA, no JavaScript needed to do navigation.

Comment: @epascarello will you explain me ? how to do? i am new in this field so

Comment: @epascarello Why do one need a button at all. The web is made of hyperlinks – so just use hyperlinks like it is done since 20 years.

Comment: @feeela i have to use button instead of link

Comment: @kapil You do not know what a an anchor tag is? `<a href="foo"><button></button></a>`

Comment: @kapil Why? Tell us just one good reason. Also this is not a redirect, but a simple link. If it just should look like a button use CSS to style the link properly…

Comment: @epascarello i know what is anchor tage . but i want to use button

Comment: ok i will try .. i  know using this i can do my stuff .. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" style="height:20px;"class="button" value="Back" onclick="window.location = 'http://the-page-to-redirect-to'"></td>
```

Comment: You can't open such page without JS and you can't use the middle or right mouse button to open the link in another tab/window. You also can't copy the URL via right-mouse-click-menu. Also, one really shouldn't use inline JS as they are hard to maintain. *Use a hyperlink, if you want to place a link!*

Comment: I see what you're saying, I personally wouldn't use this solution myself, opting for a hyperlink as you said. But the question did request a solution using JS...

Comment: I guess the real question is a whole different, but the OP is presenting the thing he/she thought would be a solution as a question. Using inline JS still is a bad habit. What if I later decide to open that link in a popup and need to place another click handler on that element? If you would have set the handler from the outside, you could alter the behavior without altering the template itself.